# Create Sub folder in S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

Already i have Root bucket(Bigdate).now i want to create NEWFOLDER (year) inside Bigdate bucket in s3 bucket. then create NEWFOLDER(MONTH) inside year.

`aws s3 mb s3://bigdata` -->Bucket created

`aws s3 mb s3://bigdata/Year/` --> It not working

Comment: er - rb is a command to remove a bucket. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rb.html

Comment: Yes is my mistake   mb only

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the below syntax, this is what I am using to create bucket and subfolders. Don't forget the "/" at end of the folder name.

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket <your-bucket-name> --key <folder-name>/test.txt --body yourfile.txt
```

Comment: I tryed below cmd but error only  aws s3api put-object --bucket Bigdate --key 2016/

Comment: what error are you getting? Check my edited answer and try that test.txt file and see if the folder is getting created?

Comment: Just now i got it Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

After Googling for 2 hours, this CLI Command worked for me:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket root-bucket-name --key new-dir-name/
```

Windows bat file example:

```
SET today=%Date:~-10,2%%Date:~-7,2%%Date:~-4,4%
aws s3api put-object --bucket root-backup-sets --key %today%/
```

Comment: After googling for 2 minutes, I found this answer. You saved mine 1 hours, 58 minutes  @Ravi :thanks:

Answer (score 13):

If local file is `foo.txt`, and remote "folder" `Year` does not yet exist, then to create it, just put the file at the designated path:

```
$ aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://bigdata/Year/ --recursive
```

Or if local folder is `YearData` containing `foo.txt`, `bar.txt`,

```
$ aws s3 cp YearData s3://bigdata/Year/ --recursive
upload: YearData/foo.txt to s3://bigdata/Year/foo.txt
upload: YearData/bar.txt to s3://bigdata/Year/bar.txt
```

See also:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html
- and first, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure

Comment: I was looking for an `aws s3`-type of command (for personal consistency and experience), and this is what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. A minor point: the `--recursive` isn't needed on the first command, when a file is being uploaded, not a directory.